# Pair programming software for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, open-source, software-development, ubuntu

I'm looking for a virtual coworking environment to work with my team in a software developement. I've seen a lot of paid ones, but I image if there is some free softwares, mainly for linux which is our OS.

Requirements are:

- free use
- good for Python code
- chat available

The idea is that we can program jointly.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Marlon, please expand on the requirements and the desired goal of the software; "coworking" is exceedingly broad. Check out the [help center](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 1):

Try out [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)'s [LiveShare extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare).

This has chat, audio, live editing of code, shared terminal instances, etc. It also has the added benefit that your workspace settings are separate, so you are not driven mad by lacking keybinds you like over at your paired programmer's computer.

Set up your VSCode to work with Python and you should be good to go.

Here's a [tutorial on setting it up](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/visual-studio-code-live-share/).